# Putting a "Game" into my Single View Application in Xcode

Tags: xcode8

I am completely new to Xcode and coding in general, so I've been wanting to create an app where I will have a UI (Start menu, options menu etc) then when the player presses the "start" button, it will bring them to a game.

When I was toying around with Xcode, I realized that if you choose the Game option instead of the single-view application, it will create Spritekit Scene and various tabs needed to create a basic game.

So I was wondering is it possible to add all those tabs needed into my SingleViewApplication or do I have to copy everything from my current game to a new project with the "Game" preset?

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you can just copy the appropriate files from a "Game" project to a "Single View Application" project, because the Game project template essentially adds a single view controller in the storyboard and put an `SKView` in the VC. I have never done this before though.

What you need to copy:

- The view controller from the storyboard of the Game (You need to connect this VC to the existing VCs in your SingleViewApplication of course.)
- The class of the VC (remember to set this as the class of the VC if it is not set)
- The `SKScene` subclass(es)
- The `sks` files
- all the graphics in the assets catalog

However, I don't recommend you doing this because `UIView`s components feels very different from `SKNode`s. This might make your app's style inconsistent. I suggest doing all the menus and stuff in `SpriteKit` as well.